# Can I use jQuery to change the contents of links on a page?

Tags: jquery

I have HTML looking like this:

```
<div id="control">
    <a href="/xx/x">y</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/C003Q/x" class="dw">x</a></li>
        <li><a href="/C003R/xx" class="dw">xx</a></li>
        <li><a href="/C003S/xxx" class="dw">xxx</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way using jQuery that I can easily change this HTML to look like the HTML below where every link has text that is enclosed in a `<span>` and where every
`href` is changed to `data-href`?

```
<div id="control">
    <a data-href="/xx/x" ><span>y</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a data-href="/C003Q/x" class="dw"><span>x</span></a></li>
        <li><a data-href="/C003R/xx" class="dw"><span>xx</span></a></li>
        <li><a data-href="/C003S/xxx" class="dw"><span>xxx</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#control a").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.html("<span>" + $el.text() + "</span>")
        .data('href', $el.attr('href'))
        .removeAttr('href');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3pTw/1/)

Comment: I am sorry. I made a mistake with the dw class. Can you please see my revised question where not all the links have the class dw.

Comment: Also is there a way that I can also change href to data-href? I had this in the question but maybe you missed it. Thanks

Comment: @Anne again, see the update :) Note that you wont see the `data-href` attribute in code as it's stored in jQuerys internal cache, but it will be accessible via `var href = $el.data('href')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use each() to iterate through elements of type `a` which have `class` `dw` .

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VgBGk/)**

```
$('#control a.dw').each(function(){  
    $(this).html("<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>" );
});
```

If you want to do the same for elements having href like `/x` then you need to change the selector.

```
$('#control a[href*="/x"]').each(function(){  
    $(this).html("<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>" )
     .attr('data-href', $(this).attr('href'))
     .removeAttr('href');;
});
```

Comment: I am sorry. I made a mistake with the dw class. Can you please see my revised question where not all the links have the class dw. Also is there a way that I can also change href to data-href?

Comment: I have updated my answer with new selector and replacing href with data-href

Answer (score 1):

You  can use `wrapInner` and `data` methods.

```
$('#control a').each(function(){
    $(this).data('href', this.href).wrapInner('<span></span')
    // $(this).attr('data-href', this.href)
    //                       .removeAttr('href') // not a good idea
    //                       .wrapInner('<span></span>')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ck6zh/

Comment: But will this change href to be "data-href". It looks like it works the other way around.

Comment: @Anne `data` is a property not an attribute, using `data` method value is stored in dataset object, if you wanna see the attribute, you can use `attr` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the href tag to data-href tag like this

```
var foo=$("#control").html();
foo=foo.replace(/href/g,"data-href");
$("#control").html(foo);
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/fXM4G/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, change every href attribute to data-href and then add the span tag:

```
$("#control").find('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-href',$(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
    $(this).html("<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>" );
});​​​​​​​​
```